# Get GrandParent and Parent info from the children id with level in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data, levels

I would like to retrieve the information (ID and CODE) of the Grand Parent (TOP Level) and the Parent from the Children Id in a query thanks to the ORACLE feature "CONNECT BY". The best could be to retrieve the complete historical data (all ancestors and children in a same query).

Here the data:

```
ID     |  CODE     |  PARENT_ID
5953   |  COMPANY  |  
230928 |  D        |  5953   
7246   |  C        |  230928 
243928 |  C.5      |  7246   
240961 |  C.3      |  7246   
7287   |  C.4      |  7246   
7286   |  C.2      |  7246   
7285   |  C.1      |  7246
```

Here the results that I want:

```
CHILDREN_ID | CHILDREN_CODE | PARENT_ID | PARENT_CODE | GRANDPARENT_CODE
5953        |  COMPANY      |           |             |  
230928      |  D            |  5953     |  COMPANY    |  
7246        |  C            |  230928   |  D          |  COMPANY
243928      |  C.5          |  7246     |  C          |  D
240961      |  C.3          |  7246     |  C          |  D
7287        |  C.4          |  7246     |  C          |  D
7286        |  C.2          |  7246     |  C          |  D
7285        |  C.1          |  7246     |  C          |  D
```

I created this query:

```
SELECT ID AS "CHILDREN_ID", CODE AS "CHILDREN_CODE", PARENT_ID , PARENT_CODE,  CONNECT_BY_ROOT CODE "GRANT_PARENT_CODE"
FROM PERSONS
WHERE LEVEL > 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR ID = PARENT_ID
```

But I don't retrieve the correct information for the Grand parent.

Could you please help me with that ?

Comment: Hi, please provide us with test data and desired output please

Comment: You need to `start with parent_id is null` to build a hierarchy from the root and use `join` to the `persons` table to get parent of parent, because `connect_by_root` retrieves the information from the root of a hiarerchy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I made it! Query itself looks scary, but I'll explain:

```
select p.id children_id, 
       p.code children_code, 
       p.parent_id, 
       prior p.code parent_code,
       case when level = 2 then null
            when level = 3 then
              connect_by_root code
            else 
              substr(sys_connect_by_path(code, '\'), 
                     instr(sys_connect_by_path(code, '\'), '\', 1, 2)+1, 
                     (instr(sys_connect_by_path(code, '\'), '\', 1, 3)) - (instr(sys_connect_by_path(code, '\'), '\', 1, 2)+1)) 
       end grandparent_code,
       case when level = 2 then null
            when level = 3 then connect_by_root to_char(id)
            else substr(sys_connect_by_path(id, '\'), 
                 instr(sys_connect_by_path(id, '\'), '\', 1, 2)+1, 
                 (instr(sys_connect_by_path(id, '\'), '\', 1, 3)) - (instr(sys_connect_by_path(id, '\'), '\', 1, 2)+1)) 
   end grandparent_id
  from persons p
  connect by prior p.id = p.parent_id
  start with p.parent_id is null;
```

I did use connect_by_path in order to display a path from root towards to child entry. See the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions164.htm) for details.

It will provide path like '..\grand-grand-parent\grand-parent\parent\child' so just subst out grand parent is left. Exceptions are cases when level = 2 (no grand-parent) and level3 when it is enough to display just a root.

I hope this will help you. Anyway +1 from me for an interesting question

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0fe9c4daa2430c1c50e0f92d80e80cef)

Comment: Thanks, I tried this query but unfortunately I obtained no result

Comment: @coeurdange57 hmmm. It did work on test data you've provided with. I added link to the dbfiddle so check it please and perhaps you need to fix something in test data or you need to adjust my answer to your real data

Comment: Sorry I'm wrong I tested and it's working. I just add `START WITH 5953` (in fact the code for the top level is null and not "Company" ). But Could you tell me please how I can add also the grandparent_id inside the query ?

Comment: @coeurdange57 you just need to replace "code" with "id" in the grandparent_code column calculation. I've updated my answer grandparent_id column

Answer (score 1):

This can be done relatively simply using a recursive sub-query factoring clause:

```sql
WITH rsqfc ( children_id, children_code, parent_id, parent_code, grandparent_id, grandparent_code ) AS (
  SELECT id,
         code,
         NULL,
         NULL,
         NULL,
         NULL
  FROM   persons
  WHERE  parent_id IS NULL
UNION ALL
  SELECT p.id,
         p.code,
         r.children_id,
         r.children_code,
         r.parent_id,
         r.parent_code
  FROM   rsqfc r
         INNER JOIN persons p
         ON ( r.children_id = p.parent_id )
)
SELECT *
FROM   rsqfc
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE persons(id, code, parent_id) AS
  SELECT   5953, 'COMPANY',  NULL FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 230928, 'D',        5953 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   7246, 'C',      230928 FROM DUAL UNION ALL  
  SELECT 243928, 'C.5',      7246 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 240961, 'C.3',      7246 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   7287, 'C.4',      7246 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   7286, 'C.2',      7246 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT   7285, 'C.1',      7246 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> CHILDREN_ID | CHILDREN_CODE | PARENT_ID | PARENT_CODE | GRANDPARENT_ID | GRANDPARENT_CODE
> ----------: | :------------ | --------: | :---------- | -------------: | :---------------
>        5953 | COMPANY       |      null | null        |           null | null            
>      230928 | D             |      5953 | COMPANY     |           null | null            
>        7246 | C             |    230928 | D           |           5953 | COMPANY         
>      243928 | C.5           |      7246 | C           |         230928 | D               
>      240961 | C.3           |      7246 | C           |         230928 | D               
>        7287 | C.4           |      7246 | C           |         230928 | D               
>        7286 | C.2           |      7246 | C           |         230928 | D               
>        7285 | C.1           |      7246 | C           |         230928 | D
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=243e1b5f36e105afd16d74bb3c6b8830)*

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to calculate attributes of some intermediary nodes in hierarchy is to use recursive `with` where you have a control over calculation on each step. But for this particular case you need just attribute of a parent, so you can go with hierarchical query over joined first result:

> ```
> with persons(id, code, parent_id) as (
>   select 5953, 'COMPANY', null from dual union all
>   select 230928, 'D', 5953 from dual union all
>   select 7246, 'C', 230928 from dual union all  
>   select 243928, 'C.5', 7246 from dual union all
>   select 240961, 'C.3', 7246 from dual union all
>   select 7287, 'C.4', 7246 from dual union all
>   select 7286, 'C.2', 7246 from dual union all
>   select 7285, 'C.1', 7246 from dual    
> )
>
> select
>   p.id children_id, 
>   p.code children_code, 
>   p.parent_id,
>   pp.code parent_code,
>   prior pp.code as grandparent_code
> from persons p
>   left join persons pp
>     on p.parent_id = pp.id
> start with p.parent_id is null
> connect by prior p.id = p.parent_id
> ```
>
> ```
> CHILDREN_ID | CHILDREN_CODE | PARENT_ID | PARENT_CODE | GRANDPARENT_CODE
> ----------: | :------------ | --------: | :---------- | :---------------
>        5953 | COMPANY       |      null | null        | null            
>      230928 | D             |      5953 | COMPANY     | null            
>        7246 | C             |    230928 | D           | COMPANY         
>        7285 | C.1           |      7246 | C           | D               
>        7286 | C.2           |      7246 | C           | D               
>        7287 | C.4           |      7246 | C           | D               
>      240961 | C.3           |      7246 | C           | D               
>      243928 | C.5           |      7246 | C           | D
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=dc01e2fdc31b1c4d58196bba3c9af37d)*